# Failed to configure an environment for GSWD lessons

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, chef-infra

I want to configure an evirinment to take Django lessons from [enter link description here](http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com)
The main problem that I'm getting errors with instalation of some Ruby gems.

At first I've got an error that told that mixlib is not installed because it requires ruby 1.9.3. 
So, I've changed 11th string of the postinstall.sh file like this

```
The version of Ruby to be installed supporting the Chef and Puppet gems
ruby_ver="1.9.3-p429"
```

So then I've rerun postinstall.sh script. But I've got an error

```
ERROR:  Error installing chef:
ohai requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

To fix that I've installed Ruby 2.1 and set it to use by default, then installed chef.

After I've logoff, run vagrant ssh, typed the pass. The inputed ls and there weren't synced files from host machine. I've run sudo ./postinstall.sh again and got the ohai version error.

Is there any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That example is badly out of date with the following list of problems:

1. Chef is now installed using an omnibus package which contains an
   embedded ruby. No more mucking around with gem installs.
2. Vagrant now supports a chef zero provisioner, big improvement over chef-solo and will also install chef.
3. Old format Vagrantfile. V2 has introduced a number of incompatible changes.
4. That example uses Ubuntu 12.04 which is no longer supported.
5. The "aws" cookbook under the "cookbooks" directory has invalid metadata causing chef to fail.... In fact all the cookbooks look out of date.

   ==> default: [2015-04-11T20:04:06+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook loaded at path(s) [/tmp/vagrant-chef/046103d02209a201a2d21ece6c21437c/cookbooks/aws] has invalid metadata: The `name' attribute is required in cookbook metadata

Tutorial needs a substantial re-write, sorry. (If the code was in github that might encourage others to help refactor it)

Comment: Oh... Thank you a lot, I've thought that I'm doing something wrong.